# Translating Nebular Calendar component

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm trying Nebular UI library for Angular (https://akveo.github.io/nebular) to see its capabilities for future projects and it has almost everything I need usually but i18n support. In particular, I'd like to translate the strings in the calendar and calendar range components (`NbCalendarComponent` and `NbCalendarRangeComponent`) but I don't see any options I can modify.

Any suggestion on this? Thanks!

Comment: I've never used this component so I can't provide specific adivce, but a quick search shows a [github issues thread](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1225) discussing i18n for the calendar, but it seems like it might still be an open issue. Perhaps something in there might help you?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above in the Github thread by @Rich, I've changed the `LOCALE_ID` of the application to match my language and now the month/day names in the Calendar component are shown correctly. There's still a minor problem, which is that the 'Today' text is not translated, but I've removed the calendar header. Until the component features multilingual support, I'll use this solution for the application.

Cheers,